# Synchronizing two different SVN URLs

Tags: svn, synchronization

I have two SVN URLs:
URL1: `http://svnURL1/data`
URL2: `http://svnURL2/data`

Both the SVN are hosted on different machines.

What I want is whenever user check in\commits any thing in the URL1, it should automatically sync with URL2.

I have tried with `svnadmin hotcopy` but its saying that **source repository should be be local**.

Please advise what should I do to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a mirror you can use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnsync.c.sync.html).
More details: [Repository Replication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication)

If you don't want to mirror your repository you should go into more details. Furthermore this would get a lot more difficult.